# OpenCV Mats of Type Float and Matrix Multiplication

Tags: opencv, matrix-multiplication, opencv3.0

In OpenCV, why are the types for matrix multiplication (gemm, not mul) restricted to floats (CV_32FC1, CV_64FC1, etc.)? Are there other ways to perform matrix multiplication with other types in OpenCV?

Comment: what kind of data type would you like? Aren't you afraid of going out of your data type range?

Comment: I wanted two CV_32SC1 matrices to multiply with each other, but it's not possible. I'm not sure what you mean by data type range, but the values I'm using aren't particularly large, so it doesn't exceed the maximum of a signed int.

Comment: so your input data is signed int, or did you transform it to signed int yourself? but opencv maybe didnt add int gemm because of exceeding maximums in general... your task would be quite special (using signed int but not using the whole range of its values in your input). Afaik there is no integer gemm in opencv, but you could write a function to perform it yourself?!?